# C/C++ in Linux for curl/curl.h

Tags: c, linux, libcurl

We are using CentOS6 (Linux) and trying to connect the webserver through C/C++ only.

**My research:**
             I found the curl library which able to communicate webserver
so I installed ubuntu-7.22.0 version in http://curl.haxx.se/download.html

I was able to include "curl/curl.h" but not able to compile their methods.

**Problem:**

Please let me know the correct version of curl for our platform and how to add -lcurl for compilation. (eg: g++ -lcurl api api.c)

Kindly give the detail explanation because it is more important to me. Thanks in advance.

-Vasanth

Comment: You mention both CentOS and Ubuntu. You should tell us what distribution you are using, and stick to it. Alternatively (but harder and probably useless) you could compile `libcurl` from its source.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your issue is not specific to `curl`: the order of arguments to `gcc` is important: compiler options, then source files, then object files, then libraries (from high-level to low-level); so try to compile with

```
 gcc -Wall -g prog.c -lcurl -o binprog
```

or (for a C++ program)

```
 g++ -Wall -g otherprog.cc -lcurl -o binotherprog
```

Of course you need the development package e.g. `libcurl-dev` or `libcurl3-gnutls-dev` or `libcurl4-gnutls-dev` (packaged in Ubuntu); on your CentOS distribution it might be called `libcurl-devel` or something else.

<sup>You should install the development package (for `libcurl`) provided by your distribution, not from http://curl.haxx.se/download.html</sup>

Actually, you should also learn how to use GNU `make` (the builder) and `gdb` (the debugger).

Answer (score 1):

with `gcc` (and variants)

the library must be last in the link command.

This is because the linker processes the command line parameters in left to right order.

If the libraries are before the object files, then when the libraries are processed, there are no unresolved external references to be resolved.

After processing the object files, then there are unresolved external references, so the library(s) must be last.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you should proceed

Install curl from this link
http://curl.haxx.se/download.html
if you have already installed this go on to this page

Then follow this tutorial
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html

Comment: I believe that installing the development package for `libcurl` provided by your distribution is simpler and wiser.

Comment: yes, i agree . I gave him the that so he knows where to look in case of problems. I have installed libcurl even the latest one. Its staightforward. Also the tutorial links gives all that is need to use libcurl